# How can i find this universal cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I have $X = \{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 = 1, z = 0\}$ and $Y = \{(x,y,z)| (x-1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$.
What is the universal cover of $X \cup Y$?

Comment: The universal cover of a diamond ring is a string of Christmas lights. :)

Comment: It may help to visualize what the space looks like first. $X$ is a circle of radius 1 in the $xy$-plane, centered at the origin. $Y$ is a sphere of radius 1 centered at $(1,0,0)$

Answer (score 2):

@Wvk is correct in his answer, the universal cover looks exactly like the universal cover of the wedge of two circles pictured below,

> [image: screenshot]

except that every node of this graph has to be replaced by a sphere like so:

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

$X \cup Y$ is sphere union two (kind of) diameters. So I think the universal cover is like:
[image]